# Detect DOM modification in Internet Explorer

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, bho

I am writing a Browser Helper Object for ie7, and I need to detect DOM modification (i.e. via AJAX).
So far I couldn't find any feasible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use [IMarkupContainer2::CreateChangeLog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa703624(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

The best thing I could recommend is the [Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=E59C3964-672D-4511-BB3E-2D5E1DB91038&displaylang=en) which allow you to view changes in the DOM.